# How to Minimize ngx-bootstrap Accordion box?

Tags: html, resize, accordion, ngx-bootstrap

I have an accordion in Html

```
<accordion [isAnimated]="true">
      <accordion-group heading="Date Created">
        {{ example text }}
      </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
```

I want to reduce the size of the box, text and the text when clicked. Basically reduce the size of entire box. How to do that?
[image: Before click]
[image: After ckick]

I have tried these below which reduce the Header text and body text but not the box

```
<accordion-group panalClass="xyz">
        <button
          class="btn btn-link btn-block clearfix"
          accordion-heading
          type="button" panalClass="xyz"
        >
          <div class="pull-centre float-centre" style="background-color: blue;">
            Date Created
          </div>
        </button>
        {{ example text }}
      </accordion-group>
```

I want to align the element with rest of the page.

[image: Rest of the page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didnt find an option to resize it I found out that I have to use the angular generated classes (Shadow CSS concept) which can be seen in the elements section in console page. In this case it was ".panel-heading" and ".panel-body".

Use the angular class within your own class to make the effect IN styles.css to get the effect. Like this:

```
.accordion-small {
  .panel-heading {
    padding: 0px;
  }
}

.accordion-small {
  .panel-body {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: small;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

In html:

```
<accordion [isAnimated]="true" class="accordion-small">
      <accordion-group>
        <button
          class="btn btn-link btn-block clearfix"
          accordion-heading
          type="button"
        >
          <div class="pull-centre float-centre header-name">
            Date Created
          </div>
        </button>
        {{ example text }}
      </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
```

In component css

```
.header-name {
  font-size: small;
}
```

Result:

[image: resized component]

Answer (score 0):

Another way is you can use `[panelClass]="customClass"` to define the custom styling for your ngx-bootstrap accordion.

In css:

```
.custom-accordion-style {
    /*any size you want*/
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: small;
}
```

In ts:

```
customClass='custom-accordion-style';
```

In html:

```
<accordion [isAnimated]="true">
    <accordion-group [panelClass]="customClass">
        <button class="btn btn-link btn-block clearfix"
            accordion-heading
            type="button">
            <div class="pull-centre float-centre">
                Date Created
            </div>
        </button>
        {{ example text }}
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```